# Same Activity Reopens after Pressing Submit Button in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I press the submit button same activity reopens (clearing all checked radio buttons). This happens only when the user is already registered.

Using firebase when user is new then new activity opens (MatchFind.class) which is correct.

**Main Part of Code**

```
bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                int id1 = r1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id2 = r2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id3 = r3.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id4 = r4.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id5 = r5.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id6 = r6.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id7 = r7.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id8 = r8.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id9 = r9.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id10 = r10.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                if (id1 == -1 || id2 == -2 || id3 == -1 || id4 == -1 || id5 == -1 || id6 == -1 || id7 == -1
                        || id8 == -1 || id9 == -1 || id10 == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(Questions.this, "Please Answer All The Questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id1);
                    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id2);
                    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id3);
                    rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id4);
                    rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id5);
                    rb6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id6);
                    rb7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id7);
                    rb8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id8);
                    rb9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id9);
                    rb10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id10);

                    getAnswers();

                    /*for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                        current_user_db.child("answer"+i).setValue(ans[i]);
                    }*/

                    current_user_db.child("answer"+1).setValue(ans[1]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+2).setValue(ans[2]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+3).setValue(ans[3]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+4).setValue(ans[4]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+5).setValue(ans[5]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+6).setValue(ans[6]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+7).setValue(ans[7]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+8).setValue(ans[8]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+9).setValue(ans[9]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+10).setValue(ans[10]);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Questions.this, MatchFind.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Full Code**

```
public class Questions extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private Button bSubmit;

    private RadioGroup r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10;
    private RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6, rb7, rb8, rb9, rb10;
    private String ans[] = new String[11];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_questions);

        bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);

        r1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ1);
        r2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ2);
        r3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ3);
        r4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ4);
        r5 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ5);
        r6 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ6);
        r7 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ7);
        r8 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ8);
        r9 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ9);
        r10 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rGroupQ10);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDatabase.child(user_id);
                int id1 = r1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id2 = r2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id3 = r3.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id4 = r4.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id5 = r5.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id6 = r6.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id7 = r7.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id8 = r8.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id9 = r9.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                int id10 = r10.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                if (id1 == -1 || id2 == -2 || id3 == -1 || id4 == -1 || id5 == -1 || id6 == -1 || id7 == -1
                        || id8 == -1 || id9 == -1 || id10 == -1) {
                    Toast.makeText(Questions.this, "Please Answer All The Questions", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id1);
                    rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id2);
                    rb3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id3);
                    rb4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id4);
                    rb5 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id5);
                    rb6 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id6);
                    rb7 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id7);
                    rb8 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id8);
                    rb9 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id9);
                    rb10 = (RadioButton) findViewById(id10);

                    getAnswers();

                    /*for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                        current_user_db.child("answer"+i).setValue(ans[i]);
                    }*/

                    current_user_db.child("answer"+1).setValue(ans[1]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+2).setValue(ans[2]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+3).setValue(ans[3]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+4).setValue(ans[4]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+5).setValue(ans[5]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+6).setValue(ans[6]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+7).setValue(ans[7]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+8).setValue(ans[8]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+9).setValue(ans[9]);
                    current_user_db.child("answer"+10).setValue(ans[10]);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Questions.this, MatchFind.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getAnswers() {
        if (rb1.getText().toString().equals("Long Term Relationship"))
            ans[1] = "a";
        else
            ans[1] = "b";

        if (rb2.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[2] = "a";
        else
            ans[2] = "b";

        if (rb3.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[3] = "a";
        else
            ans[3] = "b";

        if (rb4.getText().toString().equals("Bollywood Movies"))
            ans[4] = "a";
        else
            ans[4] = "b";

        if (rb5.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[5] = "a";
        else
            ans[5] = "b";

        if (rb6.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[6] = "a";
        else
            ans[6] = "b";

        if (rb7.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[7] = "a";
        else
            ans[7] = "b";

        if (rb8.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[8] = "a";
        else
            ans[8] = "b";

        if (rb9.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[9] = "a";
        else
            ans[9] = "b";

        if (rb10.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
            ans[10] = "a";
        else
            ans[10] = "b";
    }
```

**FindMatch.java**

```
public class MatchFind extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_match_find);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this your full code?

Comment: Please add a full code of your Questions class and MatchFind class. I can assume that in MatchFind activity you used the same layout by mistake.

Comment: @VadimsSavjolovs nope i have used correct layout file

Comment: @Ahamed it's not full code but remaining part is not important here

Comment: @Ahamed i have added the full code after the Main Part of Code

Comment: @Ahamed Added in the end

Comment: you retrieve all radio buttons using r1,r2,r3,r4,r5..like that.

Comment: getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns the id of the RadioButton(or -1 if no RadioButtons are checked) that is checked in the Radiogroup

Comment: you dont understand about radiobutton and radiogroup. you are making too many mistakes in basic level

Comment: @Ahamed In my scenario i had to do it like this only and its working for me. But that's not the problem here. Problem is when i press the Submit button  it reloads the same activity with none of the radio buttons checked. Instead it should open the `MatchFind` activity

Answer (score 0):

add this flag,FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK, and call finish() before starting your activity.Perform a clean,then reboot , Preferably invalidate and restart to clear cache.

Comment: Did you add the flag to the intent

Answer (score 0):

Are You using firebase authentication  for sign in users . You need to implimet Firebase AuthStateListener( ) in On create. And check whether  user is signed in Or not there.  if user is signed in auth state changed and you can implimet  your button on click there.

Comment: in which activity you are registering users.

Comment: That's The registration activity. This activity (for which the code is mentioned) opens after successful registration.

Comment: Did firebase database is updated after you click submit button. I think problem  is in your String user_id.  The flow goes like this when user first time get registred  firebase auth state get changed and you can get the current user_id . and you put it in as child.  Hence database operation get successful.  But When user is already registered  you are not getting current user id.

Comment: Data on the firebase gets changed every time.